# How do I display only the list items that will fit on screen in WPF?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

I have an application that will have a dashboard like interface for the main screen, and I need to display a list of recent items in the top left of the screen... each item view will be a fairly tall item displaying quite a bit of data... I want to only display the items that will fit on the screen in the area that the control is in... I don't want to have a scroll bar, and I don't want an item to be cut off partially...

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know heights of your items, you can always go through them and see if they fit into "ActualHeight" of the main screen. Using this approach you will have to track size changes from main screen and your "recent item" (if it's interactive).

The easier way would be to [write a custom panel](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control), and let it measure/arrange its children according to your rules. This way you will not have  to track size changes...